# Is it possible to push data from one vue app to another?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a page where I have two Vue apps. I can't combine them because I have Google ads interspersed around the page and Vue does not allow any script tags in the instance.

I want a way of using something similar to `props` as a way to push data from App1 to App2.

Eg: a user fills out an input in App1, Vue retains the data via v-model and also sends that data to App2.

I want to use this to filter through keywords entered in App1 and display Businesses who correspond to those keywords in App2.

Is this possible and if so does Vue have a built in feature I can use?

Comment: Typically via a bus. But you could share common data as well if needed. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [bus](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication).

```
const bus = new Vue();

new Vue({
  el:"#app-one",
  methods:{
    sendMessage(){
      bus.$emit('send-message', "hello from app one!")
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el:"#app-two",
  data:{
    message: null
  },
  mounted(){
    bus.$on("send-message", message => this.message = message);
  }
})
```

[Example](http://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/xqayPB?editors=1010).

You can also share data between two Vues.

```
const shared = {
  message:null
}

new Vue({
  el:"#app-one",
  data:{
    shared
  }
})

new Vue({
  el:"#app-two",
  data:{
    shared
  }
})
```

[Example](http://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/ryZqJq?editors=1010).

Comment: BTW how did you become so good at Vue? It's like you know everything.

Comment: @ClintonGreen I really don't. Compared to other frameworks, though , I do find Vue very flexible and intuitive. I wrote Angular 1 apps for about 3 years prior. I've been using Vue for real work for about seven months Answering questions here does help me learn things I don't know. In my opinion, if you know javascript well, Vue comes pretty naturally. A lot of the questions that come up here are more javascript questions than Vue.

Comment: Sorry to bug you again, this solution works perfectly except on elements which are controlled by components. What needs to change in order for them to work?

Comment: @ClintonGreen which one? The bus or shared data? Do you have an example you can show me (jsfiddle/codepen)?

Comment: Here's an example, if you click on the radio button in App One, nothing is updated in App Two. However if you click on the button after clicking on a radio button. That value will update App Two. https://jsfiddle.net/clintongreen/nk5ggonx/

Comment: Thanks, that's it. You legend.